# Is there any drawback to not to use LZ4 compression instead ZLIB in PHP?

Tags: php, compression, lz4

I tried to look for any benchmark, more info for PHP LZ4 compression, but I can not find much info.

I saw https://github.com/kjdev/php-ext-lz4 - but I am missing benchmark, specially:

- de/compression ratio
- de/compression time
- de/compression memory requirements

I am storing a lot of data as serialised (igbinary), I am using gzcompress() for now, wondering, if I should switch to lz4.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to have a look at these data: http://catchchallenger.first-world.info//wiki/Quick_Benchmark:_Gzip_vs_Bzip2_vs_LZMA_vs_XZ_vs_LZ4_vs_LZO

Should be quite helpful for your decision.

On the other hand, IMHO there's no disadvantage of using LZ4, it might just be not as widespread as gzlib, but if you are using it only on your server, this shouldn't be problematic.

Comment: thanks. I saw that page before, I would like to see PHP benchmark anyway. It is my own code on own server, so with portability shouldn't be problem.

Comment: Ah OK, sorry, I missed that point. But as php-ext-lz4 is using the original LZ4 sources and just passing your data over to them, PHPs performance should not be much different to the data shown on the page I mentioned. In fact, this is pretty much the way, `gzcompress()` is also handled by PHP. Hth! :)